# Remove class after scrolling to specific height jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the hover effect when I scroll down by specific height, the code below shows the hover effects when I scroll down on mobile but didn't remove them

```js
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
      $( ".search-results-container" ).addClass("hoverclass");
      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
            $( ".search-results-container" ).removeClass("hoverclass");
        }, 250));
    });
```

```css
    .search-results-container .post_title{
        border: 4px solid black;
        padding-top: 54%;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity:0;}

    .search-results-container:hover .post_title{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1; !important}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
.search-results-container.hoverclass .post_title{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1; !important}

}
```

```html
<div class="search-results-container">
 <div class="post_title">
  <h3 class="entry_title">
    <a href="#">Josh Woodward</a>
  </h3>
 </div> 
 <div class="post_image search-results-image">
   <a href="#">
 <img src="#">  
   </a>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this

```js
$j(window).scroll(function() {    
$j( ".search-results-container" ).each(function( index ) {
     var hoverElementCor = visibility($j(this))[1];
if(0.5>=hoverElementCor<=0.6){
    $j(this).addClass('hoverclass');
}else{
    $j(this).removeClass('hoverclass');
}
});
});

/**
 * Calculates the position of a given element within the viewport
 *
 * @param {string} obj jQuery object of the dom element to be monitored
 * @return {array} An array containing both X and Y positions as a number
 * ranging from 0 (under/right of viewport) to 1 (above/left of viewport)
 */
function visibility(obj) {
    var winw = $j(window).width(), winh = $j(window).height(),
        elw = obj.width(), elh = obj.height(),
        o = obj[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
        x1 = o.left - winw, x2 = o.left + elw,
        y1 = o.top - winh, y2 = o.top + elh;

    return [
        Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - x1) / (x2 - x1), 1)),
        Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - y1) / (y2 - y1), 1))
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error $ is not defined, you can use jQuery like jQuery() or you can use latest jquery library.

Thank you

Comment: @ajaymalhortra The code is working with me I don't get any errors I'm asking about the vertically scroll height removing classes